# Navbar in Bootstrap 4 reversed and toggle inactive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-4, nav

Getting to grips with Bootstrap 4, particularly the responsive menu. I have implemented, and *extensively* read the EXACT code from their documentation as below but have a problem:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The navbar appears as reversed (icon on right of screen, menu toggle on left), and the toggle button does not do anything, and is infact collapsed by default. I have tried in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ajm90UK/pen/oGwEqd) and the same thing happens, I've also tried countless CSS amends in the Chrome dev tool and still no clue.

Am I missing something embarrassingly basic trying to set this up? Can anyone explain why I'm seeing a reversed and inactive navbar from this code? Navbar is the biggest reason I'm using this framework so really want to get it working and understand it! Thanks in advance for tips and advice.

For reference here's the [Bootstrap 4 Navbar page](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website you linked to is the latest **ALPHA** version of Bootstrap. It's now in **BETA**.

The Navbar class **toggleable** has been changed to **expand**.

Make that one change on your navclass and you'll see the difference.

**Here's the page you should visit for reference**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 2):

The style sheet you added to Codepen is for version 4.0.0-beta. But the markup you used is from the documentation of the alpha version. To make the navbar logo and button appear at their correct positions, replace your current external style sheet with this:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

To make the toggle button show the collapsed elements when it is clicked, add the following JavaScript dependencies:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js
```